# Whats wrong with this strlen() implementation?

Tags: c, debugging, strlen

```
size_t strlen(const char* c)
{
  auto *c1 = c;
  while(*c1++);
  return c1 - c;
}
```

Mistakes I could find:
* missing NULL check for `c`
* `c1` should be declared as `char` pointer (or is it required?)
* should typecast to `size_t` before returning

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you observing incorrect behaviour? If so, please tell us what you're seeing, and also what you expected instead.

Comment: `while(*c1++);` --> `while(*c1) c1++;`

Comment: Does auto work in c? Either change your tag to c++ or change auto to char.

Comment: @RobertJacobs: It does not.

Comment: @RobertJacobs That's a C++11 feature IIRC, has nothing to do with C. There is a lot wrong with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Off by 1: `while(*c1++);` --> `while(*c1) c1++;`
2. "c1 should be declared as char pointer (or is it required?)"  I would use `const char *c1 = c;`.  Need to review if `auto *c1 = c;` is OK in C11.
   [Edit] Do not see that `auto` is valid in C11 either.  Recommend `const char *c1 = c;`
3. "should typecast to size_t before returning".  `return (size_t) (c1 - c);` is a good idea as the pointer difference is type `ptrdiff_t` ( a signed integer type) and `size_t` is an unsigned integer type.  This quiets warnings such as gcc -Wsign-conversion
4. "missing NULL check for c" not needed as `strlen(const char* c)` expects pointer to a string and `NULL` is not a pointer to a string.

Comment: And 3."should typecast", not needed. +1

Comment: 4. `auto` is still a storage modifier in C, not used for automatic variable type deduction, isn't it?

Comment: As you modified your answer to say the cast is *a good idea*, could you say why would it be a good idea to add a useless cast?

Comment: Omitting the type is never correct since c99.

Comment: @ouah Not good to add a useless cast.  Yet IMO, not a useless cast.  As `ptrdiff_t` is a signed type, casting to the unsigned type `size_t` can quiet pedantic warnings.

Comment: @ouah  C11 added new semantics with `auto`.  Unclear is OP's code is C11 compliant.  IAC `const char *c1` works fine.

Comment: @chux C++ had a new `auto` semantic, I don't know any new `auto` semantic in C outside the one it had since C89.

Comment: @chux C does not require a diagnostic. Does your compiler give you a warning when you remove the cast? I mean even adding `-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic`...

Comment: @ouah Agree about `auto`.  Answer edited.

Comment: @ouah "warning: conversion to 'size_t' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]"

Comment: @chux ok my gcc version has a `-Wextra` that does not include `-Wsign-conversion` which is anyway an heresy IMHO.

Comment: Why is 3. needed if the return type is `size_t`? Just to hide a compiler warning?

Comment: @juanchopanza  The cast `(size_t)` is not needed, nor does the answer express a need.  The answer expresses how it is useful.  Code would be the same with or without the cast.  It does quiet a warning by making explicit the conversion from a signed type to an unsigned one as implied conversions are a source of unexpected behavior.  In this case code knows the difference in not ever negative so code is not trying to hide anything - but be explicit.  Such warnings are often not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you will always have an answer 1 more than it should be. You need to subtract 1 or `return c1 - c - 1`;

Comment: The analysis is correct but the workaround isn't.

Comment: @ouah. Works when I test it. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Somewhat misread your answer sorry, +1